# Java code which creates UML diagrams

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering

I'm creating a program that will reverse engineer Java Source code into a UML class diagram. I have it reading all of the method names etc already from the source code but I'm wondering if there is any inbuilt Java methods for generating UML such as something like:

```
UMLdiagram u = new UMLdiagram();
Class c = new Class();
u.addClass(c);
```

Is there anything like this or are there any external tools I could use to help draw the UML diagram given that I already know methods, class attribute names etc.

Comment: Hi @Steven, welcome to SO. No, the Java core libraries do not contain any out of the box UML drawing functionality, further I'm afraid that questions asking for tools, libraries are considered off topic on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Some tools exist for this reverse engineering.But not heard about java libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools.

Some of the tools listed are in Java, some of them are open source and some of them are able to create UML diagrams in the [XMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) format.

If you want something light-weight, then [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) together with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) can both reverse-engineer Java source code and automatically generate class diagrams with `UML_LOOK`