# Java Regular Expression for detecting class/interface/etc declaration

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that detect a new class for example:

```
public interface IGame {
```

or

```
private class Game {
```

This is what I have so far but it isn't detecting :

```
(line.matches("(public|protected|private|static|\\s)"+"(class|interface|\\s)"+"(\\w+)"))
```

Can anyone give me some pointers please?

Comment: What about final or abstract? What about generics?

Comment: are you trying to match both type of string formats?

Comment: As I understood from your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504009/java-code-which-creates-uml-diagrams you want to reverse-engineer and analyze/visualize structure of Java classes. Is the code you want to analyze syntactically correct so that it can be compiled into the Java byte code class files (reverse-engineering class dependencies from class files [can be simpler task](http://asm.ow2.org/))? Or you need to work with some hot code snippets?

Comment: I'm trying to hand my program a collection of source code files and my program will create a class diagram from this. I've decided to use Jparser to read in the files though instead of using a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex like below to match both type of string formats.

```
line.matches("(?:public|protected|private|static)\\s+(?:class|interface)\\s+\\w+\\s*\\{");
```

Example:

```
String s1 = "public interface IGame {";
String s2 = "private class Game {";
System.out.println(s1.matches("(?:public|protected|private|static)\\s+(?:class|interface)\\s+\\w+\\s*\\{"));
System.out.println(s2.matches("(?:public|protected|private|static)\\s+(?:class|interface)\\s+\\w+\\s*\\{"));
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

Comment: This is almost perfect but it won't see cases such as private class SetupMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {     sorry I should have specified in the original example. I will try adding it in myself

Comment: but you didn't put the above in your regex. I just modified your regex that's all. I didn't know about the following terms like listener, Adapter, etc. You could modify the above regex according to your needs.

Comment: That’s far away from detecting all class declarations, but the question leaves room for interpretation whether really all declarations ought to be matched. You know, there’s `enum` and `@interface` as well. Further, a class declaration doesn’t need to have any of `public`, `protected`, `private`, or `static`, e.g. `class Foo` is a valid class declaration, but a class also may have more than one modifier like in `private static final class Bar`, and we’re not talking about `private @Deprecated class ClassName` yet…

Answer (score 6):

This regex is an **incomplete** specification of Java class and interface declaration. However, it can match declarations like this:

> `abstract class X<B extends Integer,D extends java.io.InputStream,R extends Comparator<? super D>>extends java.util.ArrayList<Integer>implements java.util.Queue<Integer>,Serializable{}`
>
> `public@Deprecated interface K<D> extends Comparable<Integer>{}`

So it should be sufficient for most purpose.

Please read the code to generate the regex at the end to know exactly what was skipped. In summary, `ReferenceType`, `Annotation` are not fully incorporated into this regex since they would require recursive regex to parse properly.

The Java regex to match Java class declaration in all its g(l)ory details:

> `(?:((?:public|protected|private|abstract|static|final|strictfp|@[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?<!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart})|(?!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}))(?:public|protected|private|abstract|static|final|strictfp|@[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+))*+)[ \t\f\r\n]*+)?+(?:(?<!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart})|(?!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}))class[ \t\f\r\n]++(\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(<[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]++extends[ \t\f\r\n]++(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+|\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+))?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]++extends[ \t\f\r\n]++(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+|\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+))?+)*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)[ \t\f\r\n]*+)?+(?:(?<!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart})|(?!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}))(?:(extends[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+)[ \t\f\r\n]*+)?+(?:(?<!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart})|(?!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}))(?:(implements[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+)*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+))?+[{]`

And for Java interface declaration:

> `(?:((?:public|protected|private|abstract|static|strictfp|@[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?<!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart})|(?!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}))(?:public|protected|private|abstract|static|strictfp|@[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+))*+)[ \t\f\r\n]*+)?+(?:(?<!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart})|(?!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}))interface[ \t\f\r\n]++(\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(<[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]++extends[ \t\f\r\n]++(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+|\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+))?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]++extends[ \t\f\r\n]++(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+|\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+))?+)*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)[ \t\f\r\n]*+)?+(?:(?<!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart})|(?!\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}))(?:(extends[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+[.][ \t\f\r\n]*+\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+<[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+)(?:[ \t\f\r\n]*+,[ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+|[?][ \t\f\r\n]*+(?:(?:extends|super)[ \t\f\r\n]++\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+)?+))*+[ \t\f\r\n]*+>)?+)*+)*+)[ \t\f\r\n]*+)?+[{]`

It is generated by building up the pattern piece by piece. I reference Java Language Specification for Java SE 7 for the grammar of `NormalClassDeclaration` and [`NormalInterfaceDeclaration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1).

Here is the code to generate the monster above, including comments on which pattern is skipped:

```
// All rules never end with WhiteSpace. This allows us to check for error easier.

final static String Identifier = "\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*+";
// Heuristic to exclude any position where adding space would split an Identifier or a keyword apart
final static String TokenBoundary = "(?:(?<!\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart})|(?!\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}))";

// Optional whitespace
final static String WhiteSpaceOpt = "[ \\t\\f\\r\\n]*+";
// Compulsory whitespace
final static String WhiteSpaceCom = "[ \\t\\f\\r\\n]++";

final static String MarkerAnnotation = "@" + WhiteSpaceOpt + Identifier;
// Skipped: SingleElementAnnotation, NormalAnnotation
// Can't be included due to middle recursion
final static String Annotation = MarkerAnnotation;

final static String ClassModifier = "(?:public|protected|private|abstract|static|final|strictfp|" + Annotation + ")";
// Since the declaration
//     public@Deprecated ...
// is allowed, the space between modifiers is optional.
// Since allowing the space to be optional recognizes this invalid declaration
//     publicstatic ...
// we need to assert boundary between 2 class modifiers
final static String ClassModifiers = ClassModifier + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt + TokenBoundary + ClassModifier + ")*+";

final static String TypeVariable = Identifier;

// Skipped: ArrayType, ClassOrInterfaceType
// Can't be included, since the grammar is context-free, and this is where middle recursion occurs
final static String ReferenceType = TypeVariable;
final static String WildcardBounds = "(?:extends|super)" + WhiteSpaceCom + ReferenceType;
final static String Wildcard = "[?]" + WhiteSpaceOpt + "(?:" + WildcardBounds + ")?+";
final static String TypeArgument = "(?:" + ReferenceType + "|" + Wildcard + ")";
final static String TypeArgumentList = TypeArgument + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt + "," + WhiteSpaceOpt + TypeArgument + ")*+";
final static String TypeArguments = "<" + WhiteSpaceOpt + TypeArgumentList + WhiteSpaceOpt + ">";

final static String TypeName = Identifier + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt + "[.]" + WhiteSpaceOpt + Identifier + ")*+";
// Expanded definition of ClassOrInterfaceType = ClassType = InterfaceType
//     ClassOrInterfaceType -> TypeName  TypeArguments<opt>
//     ClassOrInterfaceType -> ClassOrInterfaceType . Identifier TypeArguments<opt>
final static String ClassType = TypeName + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt + TypeArguments + ")?+" + 
    "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt + "[.]" + WhiteSpaceOpt + Identifier + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt + TypeArguments + ")?+" + ")*+";
// Definition of ClassType and InterfaceType are identical
final static String InterfaceType = ClassType;
final static String ClassOrInterfaceType = ClassType;

final static String TypeBound = "extends" + WhiteSpaceCom + "(?:" + ClassOrInterfaceType + "|" + TypeVariable + ")";
final static String TypeParameter = TypeVariable + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceCom + TypeBound + ")?+";
final static String TypeParameterList = TypeParameter + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt + "," + WhiteSpaceOpt + TypeParameter + ")*+";
final static String TypeParameters = "<" + WhiteSpaceOpt + TypeParameterList + WhiteSpaceOpt + ">";

final static String Super = "extends" + WhiteSpaceCom + ClassType;
    
final static String InterfaceTypeList = InterfaceType + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt  + "," + WhiteSpaceOpt + InterfaceType + ")*+";
final static String Interfaces = "implements" + WhiteSpaceCom + InterfaceTypeList;

final static String NormalClassDeclaration =
    // Annotation in its fullest form can end in ), so WhiteSpaceOpt is used here for pedantic
    // It can be changed to WhiteSpaceCom to save the TokenBoundary check, since current definition always end with Identifier character
    "(?:" + "(" + ClassModifiers + ")" + WhiteSpaceOpt + ")?+" +
    TokenBoundary + "class" + WhiteSpaceCom +
    // WhiteSpaceOpt is used here, since TypeParameters starts with < and no whitespace is needed to delimit
    "(" + Identifier + ")" + WhiteSpaceOpt + 
    "(?:" + "(" + TypeParameters + ")" + WhiteSpaceOpt + ")?+" +
    // As the result, we need to check for boundary before "extends" and "implements"
    TokenBoundary + "(?:" + "(" + Super + ")"+ WhiteSpaceOpt + ")?+" +
    TokenBoundary + "(?:" + "(" + Interfaces + WhiteSpaceOpt + ")" + ")?+[{]";
    // ClassBody is skipped, and only opening bracket { is matched

final static String InterfaceModifier = "(?:public|protected|private|abstract|static|strictfp|" + Annotation + ")";
// Same as ClassModifiers, except that "final" is no longer a valid modifier
final static String InterfaceModifiers = InterfaceModifier + "(?:" + WhiteSpaceOpt + TokenBoundary + InterfaceModifier + ")*+";

final static String ExtendsInterfaces = "extends" + WhiteSpaceCom + InterfaceTypeList;

final static String NormalInterfaceDeclaration = 
    "(?:" + "(" + InterfaceModifiers + ")" + WhiteSpaceOpt + ")?+" +
    TokenBoundary + "interface" + WhiteSpaceCom +
    // WhiteSpaceOpt is used here, since TypeParameters starts with < and no whitespace is needed to delimit
    "(" + Identifier + ")" + WhiteSpaceOpt + 
    "(?:" + "(" + TypeParameters + ")" + WhiteSpaceOpt + ")?+" +
    // As the result, we need to check for boundary before "extends" here
    TokenBoundary + "(?:" + "(" + ExtendsInterfaces + ")" + WhiteSpaceOpt + ")?+[{]";
```

<sup>I am well aware CamelCase and also the fact that some constants differ by pluralization are inappropriate, but it provides a better mapping to the grammar defined in the JLS.</sup>

Here is the demo on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/jzdZUF).

Comment: How is this regex supposed to be used for detection that OP asked about, e.g. how does the regex detect `"SetupMouseListener extends MouseAdapter"`? It can determine if given sentence is grammatically valid or not valid but how does it detect the meaning? (BTW: yes, it is interesting to see how you can derive regex from grammar but it is not enough to make the answer actually useful)

Comment: @xmojmr: It have captured the extends clause and class name. Just throw in the source code for crunching.

Comment: If you "just throw in some source code for crunching" into your answer showing how it spits out "SetupMouseListener", "MouseAdapter" and "extends" when it sees "`class SetupMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {}`" then I'll give you my +1

Comment: @xmojmr: Done. My code will return `extends MouseAdapter`, but you can always capture only `MouseAdapter` by making modification to `Super`