# SonarQube - Ignoring java interaces and annotations

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to find out how to configure SonarQube to ignore interface class and annotation classes (@interface) when examining my code.  So far no success.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can set sonar exclusions in your project. which build tool do you use?

Comment: That is the point, I don’t wanna do it on maven Pom.  I wanna ser it globally inside sonarqube software so all projects are easily having the same default behavior.  But the problem is not where to configure on sonar, it is how to do it.  What should I write to provide the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

To specify which files are and are not included in an analysis go to Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Files.

You should set below properties:

- Source File Exclusions

  - Patterns used to exclude some source files from analysis.
- Global Source File Exclusions

  - Patterns used to exclude some source files from analysis. They apply to every project and cannot be overridden.

For more info [read sonarQube docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus).

Comment: That I know.  My question is regarding what to put inside the places I already know.  It is regarding the values to put on sonar.exclusions or sonar.test.exclusions in order to ignore all interfaces and all annotations (@interfaces)

Comment: Did you this type of regex @com\.example\.Interface?

Comment: Not yet, but as soon as I return to work I will try.  Not sure if it will ignore annotations because of @ symbol but I will test it.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but I had no success so far.  I tried some options, one of them using the huge regex for interface written here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507391/java-regular-expression-for-detecting-class-interface-etc-declaration and inserting it on Global Source File Exclusions.

Your original purpose inspired but it is not usable because (if I understood correctly) it defines a fix package com.example and I wanna catch any java file that defines an interface, regardless of the package.

Still looking for the answer, but thank you for your time